# Using multiple hashtags in NestList

Tags: iteration, hashing

Are multiple hashtags allowed in NestList usage? If yes, how to implement it?

Example,

```
 f[{x_, y_}] := {x + y, x - y};
 NestList[f, {100, 75}, 5]
```

My attempt,

```
 NestList[{#1+#2,#1-#2} &,{100,75},5]
```

It does not work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `Apply`.

```
NestList[Apply[{#1 + #2, #1 - #2} &], {100, 75}, 5]
```

Answer (score 8):

The argument being supplied to the function is a list. It's a single argument with head List. So, #2 cannot be bound to anything. You can either use Apply (per cvgmt's answer) or use Part:

```
NestList[{#[[1]] + #[[2]], #[[1]] - #[[2]]} &, {100, 75}, 5]
```

Answer (score 6):

```
NestList[{{1, 1}, {1, -1}}.# &, {100, 75}, 5]
```

Answer (score 6):

Use `Function` and `Apply`:

```
NestList[Apply[Function[{x, y}, {x + y, x - y}]], {100, 75}, 5]
(*{{100, 75}, {175, 25}, {200, 150}, {350, 50}, {400, 300}, {700, 100}}*)
```

Or following your attempt:

```
f := Function[{x, y}, {x + y, x - y}]
NestList[Apply[f], {100, 75}, 5]
(*{{100, 75}, {175, 25}, {200, 150}, {350, 50}, {400, 300}, {700, 100}}*)
```

Or you can define your function as a solution rule and use the resource function [SolutionRulesToFunctions](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/SolutionRulesToFunctions/) as follows:

```
ReplaceAll[ResourceFunction["SolutionRulesToFunctions"][f[{x, y}] -> {x + y, x - y}]][NestList[Apply[f], {100, 75}, 5]]
(*{{100, 75}, {175, 25}, {200, 150}, {350, 50}, {400, 300}, {700, 100}}*)
```